# Overriden method finalize() isn't called for all of the garbage objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a class Tank that has an overridden method finalize(), which prints the message:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() {
    if (full) {  // -full : boolean
        System.out.println("Error: tank " + id + " must be empty at cleanup"); // -id: int
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println("Tank " + id + " cleaned up OK");  // -id: int
    }
}
```

Then I create an array with Tanks and instatiate each of them and in a loop I am deleting every link:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    tanks[i] = null;
}
System.gc()
```

Every run I get a different combination of messages. I understand that I cannot be sure if the call `System.gc()` brings the garbage collector, however why do I have messages only for some objects but not for all? If garbage collector comes, doesn't it collect all "dead" links?

Examples of the output:

1. No 0 tank

```
Tank 4 cleaned up OK
Tank 3 cleaned up OK
Error: tank 2 must be empty at cleanup
Error: tank 1 must be empty at cleanup
```

2. Only tank 4:

```
Tank 4 cleaned up OK
```

Comment: `System.gc` - [suggests, best effort etc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--) - whether the JVM decides to do anything here is implementation (configuration, weather & phase of moon) dependent.

Comment: If you want to poke around in the guts of the GC, you can enable verbose garbage collection logging. But be prepared for lots of guts.

Comment: First of all, we do not know whether the reference you’re setting to `null` is the last reference to the particular object. Even if it is, the garbage collection behavior depends on the history of the object, when it has been created, when it was used for the last time, etc. We don’t know anything about this scenario; all we see, is code setting the first five elements of an array to `null`.

Comment: Given finalizers are deprecated and might get removed in future Java versions, you might be better off not learning how they work and how you can use them. Learn about `Cleaner` instead.

Comment: In any case, it is entirely possible that in the first example tank 0 was promoted to the tenured generation, and in the second example tanks 0 - 3 were promoted to the tenured generation, while tank 4 was still in the young/eden generation. Or they were in different regions, and the GC decide to GC one region, but not the other ,etc.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the answer, all I had in my code is this array with 5 tanks each of them was isntantiated and then assigned to null. As I can see from the answers the only way to work with gc is to admit that you can't be sure about anything)

Comment: @teapot418 I'll try, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If garbage collector comes, doesn't it collect all "dead" links?

Short answer: no

Longer answer: there are no guarantees of what will happen at garbage collection time. You have to understand that modern JVMs have implemented several GC algorithms which are usually very complex. What they will do and when will vary wildly. We don't which one your version of the JVM in your particular environment is using right now. One thing these complex algorithms try to avoid is doing a full garbage collection, where most objects that are not referenced are garbage collected. That's because such full GC events mean that the JVM needs to be stopped for some time to ensure everything is consistent. Those pause impact application performance and can cause issues like timeouts or freezes. Developers of GC algorithms try very hard to avoid those issues. So you should not assume a GC implementation will work in the way you are expecting.

I recommend to read about the different GC algorithms current JVM implement to understand better their complexities.